# Tabs navigation bar hides elements beneath it

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) to write a navigation bar by using `Tab`. My tab navigation bar is almost the same as [Master.jsx](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/app/components/master.jsx):

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppCanvas,
  IconButton,
  EnhancedButton,
  Mixins,
  Styles,
  Tab,
  Tabs,
  Paper} from 'material-ui';

const {StylePropable} = Mixins;
const {Colors, Spacing, Typography} = Styles;
const ThemeManager = Styles.ThemeManager;
const DefaultRawTheme = Styles.LightRawTheme;


const Master = React.createClass({
  mixins: [StylePropable],

  getInitialState() {
    let muiTheme = ThemeManager.getMuiTheme(DefaultRawTheme);
    // To switch to RTL...
    // muiTheme.isRtl = true;
    return {
      muiTheme,
    };
  },

  propTypes: {
    children: React.PropTypes.node,
    history: React.PropTypes.object,
    location: React.PropTypes.object,
  },

  childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object,
  },

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      muiTheme: this.state.muiTheme,
    };
  },

  getStyles() {
    let darkWhite = Colors.darkWhite;
    return {
      footer: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey900,
        textAlign: 'center',
      },
      a: {
        color: darkWhite,
      },
      p: {
        margin: '0 auto',
        padding: 0,
        color: Colors.lightWhite,
        maxWidth: 335,
      },
      github: {
        position: 'fixed',
        right: Spacing.desktopGutter / 2,
        top: 8,
        zIndex: 5,
        color: 'white',
      },
      iconButton: {
        color: darkWhite,
      },
    };
  },

  componentWillMount() {
    let newMuiTheme = this.state.muiTheme;
    newMuiTheme.inkBar.backgroundColor = Colors.yellow200;
    this.setState({
      muiTheme: newMuiTheme,
      tabIndex: this._getSelectedIndex()});
    let setTabsState = function() {
      this.setState({renderTabs: !(document.body.clientWidth <= 647)});
    }.bind(this);
    setTabsState();
    window.onresize = setTabsState;
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext) {
    let newMuiTheme = nextContext.muiTheme ? nextContext.muiTheme : this.state.muiTheme;
    this.setState({
      tabIndex: this._getSelectedIndex(),
      muiTheme: newMuiTheme,
    });
  },

  render() {
    let styles = this.getStyles();

    let githubButton = (
      <IconButton
        iconStyle={styles.iconButton}
        iconClassName="muidocs-icon-custom-github"
        href="https://github.com/callemall/material-ui"
        linkButton={true}
        style={styles.github} />
    );

    let githubButton2 = (
      <IconButton
        iconStyle={styles.iconButton}
        iconClassName="muidocs-icon-custom-github"
        href="https://github.com/callemall/material-ui"
        linkButton={true}/>
    );
    return (
      <AppCanvas>
        {githubButton}
        { this._getTabs() }

        {this.props.children}
      </AppCanvas>
    );
  },

  _getTabs() {
    let styles = {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan500,
        position: 'fixed',
        height: 64,
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        zIndex: 1101,
        width: '100%',
      },
      container: {
        position: 'absolute',
        right: (Spacing.desktopGutter / 2) + 48,
        bottom: 0,
      },
      span: {
        color: Colors.white,
        fontWeight: Typography.fontWeightLight,
        left: 45,
        top: 22,
        position: 'absolute',
        fontSize: 26,
      },
      svgLogoContainer: {
        position: 'fixed',
        width: 300,
        left: Spacing.desktopGutter,
      },
      svgLogo: {
        width: 65,
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan500,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 20,
      },
      tabs: {
        width: 425,
        bottom: 0,
      },
      tab: {
        height: 64,
      },
    };

    const materialIcon =
      <EnhancedButton
        style={styles.svgLogoContainer}
        linkButton={true}
        href="/#/home">
        <img style={this.prepareStyles(styles.svgLogo)} src="images/material-ui-logo.svg"/>
        <span style={this.prepareStyles(styles.span)}>material ui</span>
      </EnhancedButton>

    return (
      <div>
        <Paper
          zDepth={0}
          rounded={false}
          style={styles.root}>
          {materialIcon}
          <div style={this.prepareStyles(styles.container)}>
            <Tabs
              style={styles.tabs}
              value={this.state.tabIndex}
              onChange={this._handleTabChange}>
              <Tab
                value="1"
                label="GETTING STARTED"
                style={styles.tab}
                route="/get-started" />
              <Tab
                value="2"
                label="CUSTOMIZATION"
                style={styles.tab}
                route="/customization"/>
              <Tab
                value="3"
                label="COMPONENTS"
                style={styles.tab}
                route="/components"/>
            </Tabs>
          </div>
        </Paper>
      </div>
    );
  },

  _getSelectedIndex() {
    return this.props.history.isActive('/get-started') ? '1' :
      this.props.history.isActive('/customization') ? '2' :
        this.props.history.isActive('/components') ? '3' : '0';
  },

  _handleTabChange(value, e, tab) {
    this.props.history.pushState(null, tab.props.route);
    this.setState({tabIndex: this._getSelectedIndex()});
  },
});

export default Master;
```

Basically I removed `AppBar`, `AppLeftNav` and `FullWidthSection`.

The only problem is that the `Tabs` hides some elements beneath it, see the picture below:

[image: Tabs navigation bar]

I must did something wrong, any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your root style is fixed. It will cause the element to stick on the top. Remove it.

Comment: I want it to stick on the top and not hide elements beneath.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found `paddingTop: Spacing.desktopKeylineIncrement + 'px',` in [page-with-nav.jsx](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/app/components/pages/page-with-nav.jsx), which is the right solution.

The reason the elements beneath the navigation tab is covered is because fixed position elements are removed from the document flow and do not take up any space. So the elements are beginning at the top as if the header isn't there. What you have to do is use padding or margin to take up the space that would have been occupied by your header if it was in the normal flow.